# Rigging and weight paint issue

Tags: rigging

I am not seeing mirror x checkbox. Which should be under the weight paint option. I have even download the latest blender and no changes. Could someone help me to identify where this option is currently at?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The option will only show up if you are in weight paint mode.  It should be in the upper right hand corner of the 3D viewport just to the left of "Options".  (Looks like a butterfly followed by 'x y z' options.  Are you sure you're in weight paint mode?  If so, maybe post a screenshot of your blender window.

Comment: Might be the case that your screen is too narrow, try scrolling the mouse wheel while hovering over the top bar area to move it into view.